# I am unable to assign 'students' to different lists

Tags: python

I want to group students into two different lists according to the subjects but the function is failing to create different lists. I am aware that the instance of the list created in both cases is the same but I am unable to find a workable solution to the same.

```
def add_tolist(name, students=[]):
       students.append(name)
       return students
idc306 = add_tolist('ram')
idc101 = add_tolist('shyam')
idc101 = add_tolist('deepa',idc101)
print idc101, idc306
```

The results should be :
['shyam', 'deepa'] ['ram']

But its printing :
['ram', 'shyam', 'deepa'] ['ram', 'shyam', 'deepa']

Comment: Mutable default: https://dev.to/florimondmanca/python-mutable-defaults-are-the-source-of-all-evil-6kk

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was that your program treated the new list as not a distinct new copy, this will fix that.

```
def add_tolist(name, students=[]):
    students1 = students.copy()
    students1.append(name)
    return students1
idc306 = add_tolist('ram')
idc101 = add_tolist('shyam')
idc101 = add_tolist('deepa',idc101)
print (idc101, idc306)
```

output: ['shyam', 'deepa'] ['ram']